# RecyclerView page indicator inside view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, viewpagerindicator

currently, I am doing the page indicator for my recyclerview, the code is from [this](https://github.com/bleeding182/recyclerviewItemDecorations/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/bleeding182/recyclerviewdecorations/viewpager/LinePagerIndicatorDecoration.java)

I successfully added a page indicator, my problem is, I want my page indicator inside the recyclerview like this

[image]

added is my xml code

```
 <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/colorLightGray">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_like"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#FFF"></RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAnimalName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please add recyclerview  xml code

Comment: @Basi, it is added thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a Recycler View for this purpose . just use a ViewPager Instead with Indicators

following is a complete video for how to use ViewPager and such sliding images with indicators https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byLKoPgB7yA